pivot_longer: names_to and names_pattern
I have a wide data frame.
Year <- c(2020, 2021)
Percent_a <- c(10,10)
Percent_b <- c(12,10)
Percent_c <- c(2,4)
Percent_d <- c(4,5)

df <- data.frame(Year, Percent_a, Percent_b, Percent_c, Percent_d)

I would like to have my data is the following format:
Year  Item  Percent
2020  a     10
2020  b     12
2020  c     2
2020  d      4
2021  a     10
2021  b     10
2021  c     4
2021  d     5

I tried this:
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Year,
    names_to = c(".value", "Percent"),
    names_pattern = "(.)_(.*)",
    values_to = "Percentage"
  ) ->df_longer

It almost worked but I got something like this - what is "t"?
Year  Percent  t
2020  a        10
2020  b        12
2020  c        2
2020  d        4
2021  a        10
2021  b        10
2021  c        4
2021  d        5


The t is coming from the "t" at the end of Percent, which is the single character before the underscore. So your regex group needs to be expanded to get the full word "Percent", rather than just the last character.
Try:
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Year,
    names_to = c(".value", "Item"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.)"
  )

Output:
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   Year Item  Percent
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1  2020 a          10
2  2020 b          12
3  2020 c           2
4  2020 d           4
5  2021 a          10
6  2021 b          10
7  2021 c           4
8  2021 d           5

If you are just looking to use the entire column name as the label, you can do this:
pivot_longer(df, -Year, names_to = "Item", values_to = "Percent")

Output:
   Year Item      Percent
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1  2020 Percent_a      10
2  2020 Percent_b      12
3  2020 Percent_c       2
4  2020 Percent_d       4
5  2021 Percent_a      10
6  2021 Percent_b      10
7  2021 Percent_c       4
8  2021 Percent_d       5


Thank you it worked! However, the items are only the first letters, how do I expand them to the full word?

Hmm, I'm a bit confused. I just replicated the data format that you indicated, with just the letters in the "Percent" column. What is the full word you are looking for? "Percent_"?

It's ok I figured it out!

pivot_longer(df, -Year, names_to = "Item", values_to = "Percent", names_prefix = 'Percent_')
